# app authorization with PHP sdk

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

I'm using the [latest Facebook PHP SDK](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk) and want to simply access user data:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(  
    'appId'  => 'xxx',  
    'secret' => 'yyy',  
    'cookie' => true  
)); 
$user = $facebook->getUser();
  if ($user) { // Checks if there is already a logged in user
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's already authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
   }
}
else { 
   //Ask for bare minimum login
   $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
   header("Location: ".$login_url); 
}
```

My problem is that the `$user` is FB logged in, but `$facebook->api('/me')` not only fails, but I don't get the App authorization dialog either.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I get the following error `OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.` What to do with it.

Comment: This is a bad practice. Because if the users didn't authorize your app he will keep getting redirected to the `$login_url`!!

Comment: @ifaour and what would be a good practice for you ?

Comment: handling the case when a user clicks on "**Don't Allow**" and redirect him to another page. Otherwise you'll end up with infinite loop! Search for "Don't Allow" in the [authentication document](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually found my error so for the record:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(  
    'appId'  => 'xxxx',  
    'secret' => 'yyyyy',  
    'cookie' => true  
 )); 
$user = $facebook->getUser();
  if ($user) { // Checks if there is already a logged in user
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    // Will throw the very first time as the token is not valid
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
   }
}
// $user is null : $user is either not logged in or the token is not valid
if(!$user) { //Ask for bare minimum login
    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
   header("Location: ".$login_url); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the FB demo script at : https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php

See if that works